# How can I validate if the object belongs to the logged user, without manual validation?

Tags: validation, yii2

I'm using parent->child (master->detail) relation in Yii2 Active Record

When the user wants to edit his record, I have to validate if it belongs to the user, in all edit actions:

> Relation: Client (1) ---> (n) Comments

### Controller

```
class ClientController extends \yii\web\Controller
{

    public function actionEditComment($id) {
        // Validate if the edited comment belongs to the user
        if (($comment = Comment::findOne($id)) == null ||
            ($comment->client0->id != Yii::$app->user->id) ) {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
        if ($comment->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $comment->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view-comment', 'id' => $comment->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('edit-comment', ['comment' => $comment]);
        }
    }
}
```

### Model

```
class Comment extends ActiveRecord {
    public function getClient0() {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::className(), ['client' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

I have to put this code in the edit and delete actions, to prevent the user changing the comment id and thus edit or delete any record that does not belong to him

My final alternative is to validate always the belonging in the model and call it in the edit and delete actions, but I was wondering, if there is any other way to go with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this kind of check with [*AccessControll* filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#access-control-filter) in your controller. And check it in `matchCallback` parameter. An example:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['edit-comment', 'delete-comment'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    'matchCallback' => function($rule, $action){
                        $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
                        if (($comment = Comment::findOne($id)) == null ||
                            ($comment->client->id != Yii::$app->user->id) ) { 
                                 return false;
                        } else { 
                            return true; 
                        }
                    }
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

So now yii2 will call this validation before it run 'edit-comment' and 'delete-comment' actions.

Comment: Great, but when I tried to use this, now I have duplicated code, because I use `$comment = Comment::findOne($id)` in the matchCallback, and again in the action, like this: `public function actionEditComment($id) {
        $comment = Comment::findOne($id); # Using this find again ...`  Is there any way to avoid this?  Some kind of common object or something like that?